# MATLAB: How to find the confusion matrix after k-NN classification?

Tags: matlab, classification, knn, confusion-matrix

I am working on a Pattern Recognition project on MATLAB. I am working on fisher iris data set. I have written some code that works for k-NN classification and after done the classification I want to calculate the confusion matrix. All my attempts have failed. So, I am asking for your help to find a way to calculate the confusion matrix C.

The related part of code is presented below:

```
fold_number = 5;
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species, fold_number);

val = 1:2:5; % for these small k values there will not be an important difference
         % regarding the cp ErrorRates. The difference is going to be
         % observable for val = 1:2:100, for example!!! But the
         % exercise asks only for k = 1,3,5.

err_arr = [];

for k=val

    cp = classperf(species); % Reinitialize the cp-structure!

    for i = 1:fold_number
        test = (indices == i); 
        train = ~test;
        class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train), k);
        %class = knnclassify(meas(test,2),meas(train,2),species(train), k); % To experiment only with the 2nd feature

        classperf(cp,class,test);
    end
    err_arr = [err_arr; cp.ErrorRate];
    fprintf('The k-NN classification error rate for k = %d is: %f\n', k,cp.ErrorRate);
end  

fprintf('\n The error array is: \n');
disp(err_arr);
```

I am looking forward to reading your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the statistics and machine learning toolbox you can simply use the [confusionmat function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html). It returns the confusion matrix `C` if you give as input the known classification (`knownGroups`) and your k-nn oputput (predicted classification given by `class` in your example):

```
[C] = confusionmat(knownGroups,class)
```

Comment: Writing knownGroups do you mean the species matrix? Because when I put  confusionmat(species,class) I got this error: "G and GHAT need to have same number of rows". Species has 150 rows and class 30 rows.

Comment: Ok, I solved it I guess. What I changed is:     knowngroup = species(randperm(n));     [C] = confusionmat(knowngroup(1:30), class). Is it right?

Comment: As far as I can see I don't think the results are correct..The C matrix seems to be wrong.

Comment: The way I see is you are trying to classify the species of your test data, and since you are building the model you should already have the right species (therefore it is your `knownGroups`). However based on your train data you can get an estimate using `knnclassify`, which is given by class. Theoretically, `[C]=confusionmat(species(test),class)`should work. ALso it is always encouraging for you to say what exactly is wrong